# Change AMQP inactivity time-out

Tags: amqp, azureservicebus

as I understand, there is an inactivity time-out in AMQP protocol. It's set to 15 minutes in Azure Service Bus.

Is it possible to change that time-out? OperationTimeout is ignored in case of AMQP protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inactivity timeout in AMQP protocol is called idle-timeout of a connection. Most, if not all, client libraries support this property. The Azure Service Bus sets this value to 4 minutes. This cannot be changed but a client can set its own idle-timeout to make the service send heartbeats during idle time. If allowed by the library, the application may also overwrite the idle timer interval to send heartbeats more often.

The 15 minute timeout you mentioned seems to be the entity idle timeout. This is Service Bus specific behavior. If an entity (queue or topic) has no activity for a pre-defined time window, the entity is unloaded (meaning all protocol connections are closed). This value cannot be changed. The only way to keep the entity active is by sending messages over the sending link, or keeping an outstanding credit on the receiving link.

Comment: Could you please point to the code? On the new ASB client it looks like the default is 1 minute (https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/blob/88fadebb47278d70c66fa10b794f85f0964b3932/src/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/Constants.cs#L30)

Comment: This is client side operation timeout that applies to send/receive operations. The idle timeouts discussed above are server side settings.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to locate the documentation that would confirm this answer and can't locate any. Do you mind to share the source? Thank you.